# LEGO identification from white, grey, and blue pieces?

Tags: set-identification, star-wars

I have these LEGO parts, can anyone help me identify this LEGO set?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is part of [9525-1: Pre Vizsla's Mandalorian Fighter](https://brickset.com/sets/9525-1/Pre-Vizsla-s-Mandalorian-Fighter)

[image]